# Completion of commutative rings.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Assume that $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a commutative local ring of equal characteristic zero.  So $R$ contains the field of rationals. The well known $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $R$ provides a complete ring $\hat{R}$ whose coefficient field is isomorphic to  the residue field of  $R$. Do there exists a topological  method (completion) for providing a local Noetheiran extension $S$ of $R$ such that $S$ contains the real numbers and also contains $R$ as a dense subring.

Comment: Why does $R$ contain the field of rationals? I don't see $1/2$ being an element of the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the multiplicative subset $\mathbb{Z}\setminus(2)$.

Comment: Sorry, by the characteristic zero I meant equal characteristic zero. Then the elements of $R$ of the form $n:=1+\ldots+1$ (n times) are unit. So the localization of $R$ by the multiplicative subset $\{n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: The obvious algebraic method is to tensor over $\mathbb Q$ or another number field with $\mathbb R$. The existence of this method makes it unlikely a cleverer mathod will produce a more natural-seeming result.

Comment: Sawin@ Is $R⨂_Q\mathbb{R}$ again a local Noetherian ring? I am more interested in an extension which contains R as a dense subring. In addition, it is expected for that to be local Noetherian.

Comment: @Aurora: Since each of your two comments in effect modified the question, it might be good to edit these modifications into the question itself, so that future readers can find the intended question by simply reading it rather than reading the whole comment thread.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this can't happen: if $R$ is dense in $S$ (in the adic topology from the maximal ideal), the map on residue fields has to be surjective, and this is not the case here. 

Comment: @Akhil: That's right! A new topology is needed. In particular, if R is a field of characteristic zero then the adic toopology is useless